# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Iam getting error above for this code (line 9):

```
pair = function(x,y){
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
}

alpha = function(){
   this.field = new pair(0,0);
   this.fun = function(){
      console.log(this.field.x);
   }
}

function beta(para){
   para();
}

beta(new alpha().fun);
```

but the call like:

```
new alpha().fun();
```

works fine.

Could someone explain what's going on in this case?

Answer (score 4):

That's because the function isn't called with the right context (`this`).

You can use `bind` to ensure it's correct :

```
this.fun = (function(){
  console.log(this.field.x);
}).bind(this);
```

You could also use the closure to store the value of `this` :

```
alpha = function(){
   var a = this;
   this.field = new pair(0,0);
   this.fun = function(){
      console.log(a.field.x);
   }
}
```